# How to remove rows of one file whose first value does not appear in another file?

Tags: linux, shell

I have one file that has columns of integers -> File1

```
1 2 3
2 2 2
3 2 1
3 1 4
4 1 4
5 0 0
```

I have another file with a single column of (unique) integers -> File2

```
1
3
4
```

Both files are extremely large. I want to remove lines of File1 whose first column value doesn't appear in File2.

```
1 2 3
3 2 1
3 1 4
4 1 4
```

Comment: This can be done easily with `awk`. Please show what you tried.

Comment: I've not tried anything yet as I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: First read `File2` into an array. Then when reading `File1`, if none of the columns are in the array, print the line.

Comment: @Sasspedence, search for "NR==FNR"

Comment: ok this is what I have $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}$1 in a{print $0}'  file2 file1   // edit, needed a 0 instead of a 1 for the full line to be printed. This is incredible... so simple in shell! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this looping through the lines of File1, extracting first numbers from each line and trying to find the exact match with the numbers in File2.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
re='^[0-9]+$'

for i in $( cat File1 ); do
    num=$( echo $i | awk '{print $1}' )
    grp=$( grep "^${num}\b" File2 )
    if [[ $grp =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

You can save the output of this script in a temporary file and use it to overwrite original File1.

Comment: [Don't read the lines of a file with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)